# HIVE :- Read latest row if all coloumns matches

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I need to select rows if all the column value matches and take the latest one assume that others are duplicate to it . but if any one column data not matched with the other row I need to show both the rows.

ex 
My table sample data may look like below

[image: Sample Data]

My expected result is

[image]

I tried to get the max of it and I am getting only one row instant three rows per name.

My actual table contains 40 columns and I gave only the sample data and expected result for understanding

Comment: just use `select distinct ...`

Comment: Works as expected Thanks @VamsiPrabhala